# How to hit POST API in AMP?

Tags: api, post, amp-html

Whenever I tried I got the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

But when I hit the API using GET method, server getting the value but in that case page is getting refresh in the front end.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are trying? Or, better, a minimum (non) working version.

Comment: I hope this post will help you to get your answer, feel free to ask questions...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422257/amp-form-submission-redirect-or-response/43489796#43489796