# How to create an emailer in AMP

Tags: email-validation, amp-html

I am a new developer, working to build "mywebsite.com" site with AMP code.  I would like to create a page with input fields for user name, email address, and message.  I would like for the user to be able to input those three fields, and have an email with the user name, email address, and message delivered to "myemail@gmail.com"

Here is my HTML for the page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html AMP lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mywebsite</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">

 <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
 <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async  src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    
 <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end)   0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    
<style amp-custom>
form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success],
form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error]{
  margin-top: 16px;
}
form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success] {
  color: green;
}
form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error] {
  color: red;
}
form.amp-form-submit-success.hide-inputs > input {
  display: none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<form method="post"
  class="p2"
  action-xhr="MAILER.php"
  target="_top">
  
  <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3">
    <input type="text"
      class="block border-none p0 m0"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Name..."
      required>
    <input type="email"
      class="block border-none p0 m0"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email..."
      required>
      <input type="text"
      class="block border-none p0 m0"
      name="message"
      placeholder="Message..."
      required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit"
    value="Send"
    class="ampstart-btn caps">
  <div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      Success! Thanks {{name}} for your message.
    </template>
  </div>
  <div submit-error>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      Error!
    </template>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php file:

```html
<?php

 $source_origin = trim($_REQUEST['__amp_source_origin']);//Security
 if($source_origin != "https://mywebsite.com"){
 echo "Not allowed origin";
 return;
 }
 header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://mywebsite.com');
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;'); 

    // variables start
 $name = "";
 $email = "";
 $message = "";
 
 $name =  trim($_REQUEST['name']);
 $email =  trim($_REQUEST['email']);
 $message =  trim($_REQUEST['message']);
 // variables end
 
 // email address starts
 $emailAddress = 'admin@mywebsite.com';
 // email address ends
 
 $subject = "Message From: $name"; 
 $message = "<strong>From:</strong> $name <br/><br/> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";
 
 $headers = '';
 $headers .= 'From: '. $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
 
 $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 
 //send email function starts
 $result = mail($emailAddress, $subject, $message, $headers);

 if($result === true && !empty($emailAddress)){
  echo json_encode(array("name"=>$name,"email"=>$email));
 }else{
  header('Status: 400', TRUE, 400);
  echo json_encode(array('message'=>'This is error message'));
 }
 //send email function ends
?>
```

In the real code, I have my website URL and email in place of mywebsite.com and admin@mywebsite.com.

I have reflected the input from several on this forum, unfortunately, this isn't working at all.  There is no message to indicate that the mail was successfully sent, nor is there an error message.  In the end, there is no email sent to admin@mywebsite.com.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I create this simple web page in an AMP Valid format?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: If I understand you correct, yo need a AMP valid form. You can check the example https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/

Comment: @DavidHenderson http:// should be https://

Comment: @david please refer to this link, I hope this will be helpful to create your functionality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422257/amp-form-submission-redirect-or-response/43489796#43489796

Comment: Thank you, BlueSuiter.  I read your link carefully and attempted to execute using your code.  I posted the code to your question link.  I'm testing from the host server, where both the form.html and the mailer.php are uploaded.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I've edited the code in this string to reflect input above and make the HTML amp valid.  Unfortunately, it still isn't working.  I'm testing from the hosting server.  Both the form.html and the mailer.php reside directly in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

**MAILER.php :**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "admin@mywebsite.com";
$subject = "Message From: $name";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

       $domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ". str_replace('.', '-','https://mywebsite.com') .".cdn.ampproject.org");
        header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: " . $domain_url);
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
        header("AMP-Redirect-To: https://mywebsite.com/index.html");
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"); 
        echo json_encode(array('name' => $name));
        exit;
}
?>
```

> Replace https://mywebsite.com/ to your domain url